# Assignment to a vector by index is not affecting its value after the loop

Tags: c++, vector, assignment-operator

I'm having problems with indexed assignments in the vector STL container. 
I need to count all values of a given vector (called _assignments), so I wrote this function (with extra printing for demonstration).

```
void
MyClass::_count_values()
{
  // MyClass has _counts, _nvalues and _assignments as member variables. 
  std::vector<unsigned> counts(_counts);  
  counts.reserve(_nvalues);               
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < _nvalues; i++){
    counts[i] = std::count(_assignments.begin(), 
                           _assignments.end(), i);
    std::cout << counts[i]; // (1)
  }
  std::vector<unsigned>::iterator it(counts.begin());
  while(it != counts.end()){
    std::cout << *it << " "; // (2)
    it++;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  _counts = counts;
}
```

But it is not assigning the count data to _counts. 
Also, it only prints in (1): only a blank line is printed in (2).

Ex.
If _assignments is:

> {3,3,3,1,2,4,5}

it prints

> 11311

(in (2) the output should be spaced)

---

Edit: As suggested in the comments, I changed reserve to resize and it fixed the problem!

Comment: Use `resize`, not `reserve`. Or change the array-style access to pushing onto the back.

Comment: It worked, thanks!
I changed it to resize.